# Switch(true) always displays the default case

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I made a program in javascript that calculates the age of a person, after input of a date of birth. The age check works fine, but I am having trouble with a switch(true) case. I am trying to limit the input to certain digits, because the value for the month cannot exceed 12 and depending on the month, the day cannot exceed a certain amount.

I have tried to write the same code in if statements. It still does not function.

```js
do {
    var geboorte_datum = prompt("Voer uw leeftijd in(DD/MM/YYYY)");
    var age = getAge(geboorte_datum);
    var delen = geboorte_datum.split('/');
    var geboorte_dag = delen[0];
    var geboorte_maand = delen[1];
    var geboorte_jaar = delen[2];
    switch (true) {
        case (delen[1] === 1 && delen[0] > 31):
        case (delen[1] === 2 && delen[0] > 28 && (Number.isInteger(delen[2] / 4) === "false")):
        case (delen[1] === 2 && delen[0] > 29 && (Number.isInteger(delen[2] / 4) === "true")):
        case (delen[1] === 3 && delen[0] > 31):
        case (delen[1] === 4 && delen[0] > 30):
        case (delen[1] === 5 && delen[0] > 31):
        case (delen[1] === 6 && delen[0] > 30):
        case (delen[1] === 7 && delen[0] > 31):
        case (delen[1] === 8 && delen[0] > 31):
        case (delen[1] === 9 && delen[0] > 30):
        case (delen[1] === 10 && delen[0] > 31):
        case (delen[1] === 11 && delen[0] > 30):
        case (delen[1] === 12 && delen[0] > 31):
        case (delen[1] > 12):
            alert("U heeft uw geboortedatum verkeerd ingevuld. Probeer het opnieuw.");
            break;
        case (age > 17):
            alert("U heeft nog geen toegang tot deze site.");
            break;
        default:
            alert("Welkom.");
    }
}
while (geboorte_maand === 12 && geboorte_dag > 31 || geboorte_maand === 11 && geboorte_dag > 30 || geboorte_maand === 10 && geboorte_dag > 31 || geboorte_maand === 9 && geboorte_dag > 30 || geboorte_maand === 8 && geboorte_dag > 31 || geboorte_maand === 7 && geboorte_dag > 31 || geboorte_maand === 6 && geboorte_dag > 30 || geboorte_maand === 5 && geboorte_dag > 31 || geboorte_maand === 4 && geboorte_dag > 30 || geboorte_maand === 3 && geboorte_dag > 31 || geboorte_maand === 2 && geboorte_dag > 29 && (geboorte_jaar / 4).isInteger() || geboorte_maand === 1 && geboorte_dag > 31 || geboorte_maand === 2 && geboorte_dag > 29 && ((geboorte_jaar / 4).isInteger() === "false") || geboorte_maand > 12);
```

and my attempt with if statements:

```js
    var geboorte_datum = prompt("Voer uw leeftijd in(DD/MM/YYYY)");
    var age = getAge(geboorte_datum);
    var delen = geboorte_datum.split('/');
    var geboorte_dag = delen[0];
    var geboorte_maand = delen[1];
    var geboorte_jaar = delen[2];
    if (delen[1] === 1 && delen[0] > 31) {
        alert("U heeft uw geboortedatum verkeerd ingevuld. Probeer het opnieuw.");
    } else if (age < 18) {
        alert("U heeft helaas nog geen toegang tot deze site.")
    } else {
        alert("Welkom.")
    }
    if (delen[1] === 2 && delen[0] > 28 && (Number.isInteger(delen[2] / 4) === "false")) {
        alert("U heeft uw geboortedatum verkeerd ingevuld. Probeer het opnieuw.");
    } else if (age < 18) {
        alert("U heeft helaas nog geen toegang tot deze site.")
    } else {
        alert("Welkom.")
    }
    if (delen[1] === 2 && delen[0] > 29 && (Number.isInteger(delen[2] / 4) === "true")) {
        alert("U heeft uw geboortedatum verkeerd ingevuld. Probeer het opnieuw.");
    } else if (age < 18) {
        alert("U heeft helaas nog geen toegang tot deze site.")
    } else {
        alert("Welkom.")
    }
    if (delen[1] === 3 && delen[0] > 31) {
        alert("U heeft uw geboortedatum verkeerd ingevuld. Probeer het opnieuw.");
    } else if (age < 18) {
        alert("U heeft helaas nog geen toegang tot deze site.")
    } else {
        alert("Welkom.")
    }
    if (delen[1] === 4 && delen[0] > 30) {
        alert("U heeft uw geboortedatum verkeerd ingevuld. Probeer het opnieuw.");
    } else if (age < 18) {
        alert("U heeft helaas nog geen toegang tot deze site.")
    } else {
        alert("Welkom.")
    }
    if (delen[1] === 5 && delen[0] > 31) {
        alert("U heeft uw geboortedatum verkeerd ingevuld. Probeer het opnieuw.");
    } else if (age < 18) {
        alert("U heeft helaas nog geen toegang tot deze site.")
    } else {
        alert("Welkom.")
    }
    if (delen[1] === 6 && delen[0] > 30) {
        alert("U heeft uw geboortedatum verkeerd ingevuld. Probeer het opnieuw.");
    } else if (age < 18) {
        alert("U heeft helaas nog geen toegang tot deze site.")
    } else {
        alert("Welkom.")
    }
    if (delen[1] === 7 && delen[0] > 31) {
        alert("U heeft uw geboortedatum verkeerd ingevuld. Probeer het opnieuw.");
    } else if (age < 18) {
        alert("U heeft helaas nog geen toegang tot deze site.")
    } else {
        alert("Welkom.")
    }
    if (delen[1] === 8 && delen[0] > 31) {
        alert("U heeft uw geboortedatum verkeerd ingevuld. Probeer het opnieuw.");
    } else if (age < 18) {
        alert("U heeft helaas nog geen toegang tot deze site.")
    } else {
        alert("Welkom.")
    }
    if (delen[1] === 9 && delen[0] > 30) {
        alert("U heeft uw geboortedatum verkeerd ingevuld. Probeer het opnieuw.");
    } else if (age < 18) {
        alert("U heeft helaas nog geen toegang tot deze site.")
    } else {
        alert("Welkom.")
    }
    if (geboorte_maand === 10 && geboorte_dag > 31) {
        alert("U heeft uw geboortedatum verkeerd ingevuld. Probeer het opnieuw.");
    } else if (age < 18) {
        alert("U heeft helaas nog geen toegang tot deze site.")
    } else {
        alert("Welkom.")
    }
    if (delen[1] === 11 && delen[0] > 30) {
        alert("U heeft uw geboortedatum verkeerd ingevuld. Probeer het opnieuw.");
    } else if (age < 18) {
        alert("U heeft helaas nog geen toegang tot deze site.")
    } else {
        alert("Welkom.")
    }
    if (delen[1] === 12 && delen[0] > 31) {
        alert("U heeft uw geboortedatum verkeerd ingevuld. Probeer het opnieuw.");
    } else if (age < 18) {
        alert("U heeft helaas nog geen toegang tot deze site.")
    } else {
        alert("Welkom.")
    }
    if (delen[1] > 12) {
        alert("U heeft uw geboortedatum verkeerd ingevuld. Probeer het opnieuw.");
    } else if (age < 18) {
        alert("U heeft helaas nog geen toegang tot deze site.")
    } else {
        alert("Welkom.")
    }
```

I expected the output to display the alerts when the input exceeds the amount of days or months. For each month I added how many days the month could have. The result of the switch(true) is however always the default. The if statements code does also not work.

Comment: btw, [`Number.isInteger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) returns a boolean value, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'dates' are not numbers, but a string. Because you are using strict equality (`===`) 
So
'21' !== 21
 however
'21' == 21

In general, most people would encourage strict equality, so you may just have to convert the strings into a number using the `parseInt()` function first.

If you run `typeof delen[0]` you should see it is a string - you will need it to be a number for any of this code to work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I created a new variable named day and a variable named month.
var day = parseInt(geboorte_dag, 10);
var month = parseInt(geboorte_maand, 10);
I used these variables in my case statements.
The case statements for the wrong months work now, but the age check itself seems to have stopped functioning.

Comment: Olaf, you didn't provide source code of `getAge()`, so just try to `console.log(age)`. what value does `age`  have?

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code!

- `Number.isInteger(delen[2] / 4) === "false"` can't work because you compare a boolean value with a string.
- Same for `delen[1]`.

You can simply doing something like that:

```js
function getAge(dateStr) {
  var delen = dateStr.split('/');
  var geboorte_dag = Number(delen[0]);
  var geboorte_maand = Number(delen[1]);
  var geboorte_jaar = Number(delen[2]);

  return new Date().getFullYear() - new Date(geboorte_jaar, geboorte_maand, geboorte_dag).getFullYear(); // Not exactly...
}

function isValidDate(dateStr) {
  var delen = (dateStr || '').split('/');
  var geboorte_dag = Number(delen[0]);
  var geboorte_maand = Number(delen[1]);
  var geboorte_jaar = Number(delen[2]);
  var schrikkel_jaar = Number.isInteger(geboorte_jaar / 4);
    
  return ((geboorte_maand === 1 && geboorte_dag <= 31)
  || (geboorte_maand === 2 && geboorte_dag <= 29 && schrikkel_jaar)
  || (geboorte_maand === 2 && geboorte_dag <= 28 && !schrikkel_jaar)
  || (geboorte_maand === 3 && geboorte_dag <= 31)
  || (geboorte_maand === 4 && geboorte_dag <= 30)
  || (geboorte_maand === 5 && geboorte_dag <= 31)
  || (geboorte_maand === 6 && geboorte_dag <= 30)
  || (geboorte_maand === 7 && geboorte_dag <= 31)
  || (geboorte_maand === 8 && geboorte_dag <= 31)
  || (geboorte_maand === 9 && geboorte_dag <= 30)
  || (geboorte_maand === 10 && geboorte_dag <= 31)
  || (geboorte_maand === 11 && geboorte_dag <= 30)
  || (geboorte_maand === 12 && geboorte_dag <= 31));
}

var geboorte_datum = prompt("Voer uw leeftijd in(DD/MM/YYYY)");

if (!isValidDate(geboorte_datum)) {
  alert("U heeft uw geboortedatum verkeerd ingevuld. Probeer het opnieuw.");
} else if (getAge(geboorte_datum) < 18) {
  alert("U heeft helaas nog geen toegang tot deze site.");
} else {
  alert("Welkom.");
}
```